# how to calculate total order price with relation many to many in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i'm trying to append total price of an order contains many products, i used relation many to many to handle orders and products with pivot table (order_items).

collection like that:

[image]

every order has array of products, and every product has a pivot that has quantity.

i added new key in the order collection called "total" to calculate total of the (everyProduct * quantity) like that:
[image]

i can get sum of (price) of the product but how to get sum of (everyPriceProduct * quantity).

for example these product exist in an order:

[image]

i wanna calculate summation of  (everyPriceOfProduct * everyQuantityThatInPivot) then append the (summation) in key "total" in the order above i tried a lot but noway.

**Product Model:**

```
   <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Attribute;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;

class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;


    protected $fillable = [
        'sku',
        'name',
        'price',
    ];


    public function orders() : BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Order::class,'order_items','product_id','order_id','id','id')
            ->withPivot('qantity');
    }
}
```

**Order Model:**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Casts\Attribute;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;

class Order extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $appends = ['total'];


    protected function total(): Attribute
    {
        return Attribute::make(
            get: fn ($value) => "wanna calculate subtotal of order here (sum(everyProduct * quantity))",
        );
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'purchaser_id');
    }

    public function products() : BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class,'order_items','order_id','product_id')
            ->withPivot('qantity');
    }

}
```

**Pivot Table:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class OrderItem extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table='order_items';


    protected $fillable = [
        'product_id',
        'order_id',
        'qantity',
    ];
}
```

**route:**

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
   return  $orders = Order::with(['products','user'])->withCount('products')->take(50)->get();

    $collection = $orders->map(function ($item) {
        foreach ($item->products as $product)
        {
            $product['total'] = $product->price * $product->pivot->qauntity;
        }
});
    return $collection;
});
```

Any help please?

Comment: {{ $order->products->sum('price') }} you can do in this way when there is many to many relation already defined.....It will add the price 2 times e.g a product with price 25 and quantity 2 ,it will return 50

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to my mind is to return the prices of the products in the individual order to an array and get the sum of all the numbers in the array.

```
    $everyPriceProductArray = array(); 
    foreach ($order['products'] as $key => $item) {
        $price = $item['price'] * $item['pivot']['quantity'];
        array_push($everyPriceProductArray, $price);
    }
    $everyPriceProduct = array_sum($everyPriceProductArray);
```